# A way to add to tx_extra with current monero executables

Tags: tx-extra

**Disclaimer: This is my first ever post. Please let me know if I didn't follow the guidelines for asking a question. Thank you all.**

I have stumbled upon this issue with other questions but none answered a proper way to add some kind of sender-based data to be added in the `extra` field of a monero transaction.

Some suggested editing the monero source code and some say to use paymentID. However, with paymentID being obsolete now, I want a way to add data to the field without any restriction knowing that I won't exceed the block size of course.

If the only way is to edit the source code of monero, I had a look at the structure of the code (especially monero-wallet-rpc) and I was wondering what I can change to provide that functionality. I know I will have to change something too in the wallet-cli or the daemon but I'm still exploring.

Any guidance towards solving the problem of having the ability to add bytes to `extra` that are sender specified would be much appreciated.

Comment: This PR might be related: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/6410

Answer (score 1):

Only the old, long-form, unencrypted payment IDs are obsolete. You can still use the short (8 byte) encrypted payment IDs.

You create/attach encrypted payment IDs by using the command `integrated_address`:

```
help integrated_address 

Command usage: 
  integrated_address [device] [<payment_id> | <address>]

Command description: 
  Encode a payment ID into an integrated address for the current wallet public address (no argument uses a random payment ID), or decode an integrated address to standard address and payment ID
```

Replacing `<payment_id>` with the 8 hex bytes you want to use. The result will be an integrated address with an embedded encrypted payment ID. E.g.

```
integrated_address deadbeeffacefeed
```

More information can be found: https://web.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/paymentid.html

Comment: I'm aware that I can use short payment IDs to create integrated addresses. What I meant by restrictions in my question is the limitation of number of bytes to use. I want to use up to 32 bytes. I want to be able to store a `SHA-256` hash or something of that sort. Maybe I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: Without manually editing/constructing the tx, the only way to add extra data easily is via encrypted payment IDs. For adding 32 bytes, other potential ways could be simply splitting your 32 bytes over 4 integrated addresses or burning some funds to a fake output key.

Comment: I'm currently looking into ways of manually editing the tx. But thanks for the suggestion of splitting the message digest into 4. I might use that if nothing else works.